# Adding items to a list from within a query

Tags: c#, xml

Given the following sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSamples>
   <CodeSample language="vba">
   <!--all values in ModifierString,Parameters & ReturnType should be in lowercase-->
     <MethodName>AddNewContact</MethodName>
     <ModifierString value="public sub" />
     <Parameters>
       <Parameter parameterType ="string" parameterName ="wholeName" />
       <Parameter parameterType ="string" parameterName ="email" />
       <Parameter parameterType ="string" parameterName ="mobileNumber" />
     </Parameters>
     <ReturnType>void</ReturnType>
     <CodeLines>
        Dim outlookContact As Outlook.ContactItem
        If outlookContact Is Nothing Then
            Set outlookContact = Application.CreateItem(olContactItem)
            With outlookContact
              .fullName = wholeName
              .Email1Address = email
              .Email1DisplayName = wholeName
              .MobileTelephoneNumber = mobileNumber
              .Save
          End With
      End If
      Set outlookContact = Nothing
     </CodeLines>
   </CodeSample>
</CodeSamples>
```

I am trying to build a query to return all instances of CodeSamples with a specific language, where I am stuck is how to get the list of parameters into the query. Here is the query so far, for now just trying to get out the one sample from the xml file.

**Edited**

```
var codeSample =
        from element in xDoc.Element("CodeSamples")?.Elements("CodeSample")
        where element.Attribute("language")?.Value == "vba" && element.Element("MethodName")?.Value == methodName
        select new CodeSample()
        {
            Language = element.Attribute("language").Value,
            Modifiers = element.Element("ModifierString")?.Value,
            MethodName = methodName,
            ReturnType = element.Element("ReturnType")?.Value,
            CodeLines = element.Element("CodeLines")?.Value,
            Parameters = element.Element("Parameters")?.Elements()
                     .Select(x => new MethodParameters
                     {
                        ParameterName = x.Attribute("parameterName").‌​Value,
                        ParameterType = x.Attribute("parameterType").Value
                     })
       };
```

MethodParameters is a class

```
public class MethodParameters
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterType { get; set; }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

**Final working Code thanks to jdweng**

```
var codeSamples = xDoc.Descendants("CodeSample").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("language") == language)
            .Select(x => new  CodeSample
            {
                Language = x.Attribute("language").Value,
                Modifiers = x.Element("ModifierString")?.Value,
                MethodName = x.Element("MethodName")?.Value,
                ReturnType = x.Element("ReturnType")?.Value,
                Parameters = x.Descendants("Parameter").Select(y => new MethodParameters {
                    ParameterType = (string)y.Attribute("parameterType"),
                    ParameterName = (string)y.Attribute("parameterName")
                }).ToList(),
                CodeLines = (string)x.Element("CodeLines")
            });
```

Comment: Something along the lines of `element.Element("Parameters").Elements().Select(x => new MethodParameters{ParameterName=x.Attribute("parameterName").value, ParameterType=x.Attribute("parameterType").value)`

Comment: See edited post, the Attribute("parameterName").‌​Value, isn't liked, .Value has red squiggly saying Value doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: Probably just a unicode character when you copy/pasted. The Parameters property should be: `Parameters = element.Element("Parameters")?.Elements().Select(x => new MethodParameters{ParameterName = x.Attribute("parameterName").Value, ParameterType = x.Attribute("parameterType").Value}).ToList()`

Comment: Why don't you deserialize this xml to `[Serializable]` objects? It would be much easier and more efficient to maintain. Also, what is the exact problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("CodeSample").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("language") == "vba").Select(x => new {
                parameters = x.Descendants("Parameter").Select(y => new {
                    parameterType = (string)y.Attribute("parameterType"),
                    parameterName = (string)y.Attribute("parameterName")
                }).ToList(),
                codeLines = (string)x.Element("CodeLines")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @jdweng...with some minor modifications, working as expected. Thank you for showing me how to do the list within the query. I usually start with query syntax, then adapt to linq.